# How to create a chat application for android using Xmpp server?

Tags: android

i want to make chat in android using Xmpp i did some research and found whatsapp and other application are using this technology for it .

i just wan to figure out how can i use it to built my chat appliction .please provide some guide line or tutorial i could not find any useful links.

Comment: how do you know that whatsapp is using the same technology?

Comment: WhatsApp uses a customized version of the open standard Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp

Comment: try to learn GCM it will give idea

Answer (score 0):

You can check source files of Conversations, you can learn more from this source codes. 
[Conversations](https://github.com/siacs/Conversations)